# Postgresql Select anything / everything

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am creating a search tool for Postgres. It will have several text entries (one for each table column). When the text entry is blank, I want the query to match each and every table entry. Is this possible? I have tried:

```
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE surname = '*';
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE surname = *;
```

As you can imagine, this returns nothing since there is no surname of *, and the second query is invalid. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Because of the nature of what I am doing, a `SELECT name FROM contacts` is not sufficient. I guess I could make it work, but it would be ugly. I want a `WHERE` for every column in the table, but if the search for any given column is an empty string, I want it to fetch every entry in the table.

Comment: `where surname like '%'` or simply leave out the `where` completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I found my answer [here](http://www.internationalskeptics.com/forums/showthread.php?t=214146). The correct code is:

```
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE surname ~* '';
```

returns all entries

```
SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE surname ~* 'John Doe';
```

returns entries that have a surname of `John Doe`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree that the regex is overkill, but you're not quite right with the equivalents, because regexes match partial strings, not whole ones. So `surname ~* ''` returns all rows because every row contains the empty string, and `surname ~* 'John Doe'` would also match `'Peter-John Doe-Re-Mi'`

Comment: @IMSoP That is exactly what I found. Furthermore that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Using the more common `LIKE` pattern matching, which *does* have to match the whole string, these would be equivalent to `surname LIKE '%'` and `surname LIKE '%John Doe%'`. See also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html for details of the three different types of pattern matching supported by PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the query to match each and every table entry

Just use `SELECT` without `WHERE surname` clause. Simple as that.

```
SELECT name FROM contacts
```

But if you want to use one query, you can do it this way:

```
cur.execute(
    """SELECT name FROM contacts 
    WHERE (CASE WHEN %(entry)s != '' THEN surname = %(entry)s ELSE true END)"""
    , {'entry': "John Doe"}
)
```

---

As for your answer, you used regular expressions matching. In the question you never mentioned it. So I assume it's not what you wanted. Regular expressions have specific syntax, and if some invalid regex format is entered into the text entry, the query will fail.

Comment: I will definitely try this out when I have the time to play with it. Sorry for not having a question that is easy to understand. I knew what I was looking for but did not know what to call it, so I explained my problem. Rather poorly :( See my edit.